# MYSQL lento al ejecutar una UDF

Tags: mysql, funciones, mysql-workbench

Hace unos meses me ayudaron a desarrollar una función que calcula el costo de envío por orden; en ése entonces estaba utilizando SQL Server, sin embargo, ahora necesito hacer que funcione en MySQL.
La función ya está en MySQL, pero tarda demasiado tiempo en hacer el cálculo.
La función ocupa dos criterios, el primero es el número de orden y el segundo son los números de rastreo, dejo el código.

Ojalá me puedan ayudar, de antemano gracias.

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION `FN_FREIGHT_COST` (ORDERNUM INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(16,4)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN
        (SELECT
            SUM(FREIGHT) AS FREGIHT 
        FROM (SELECT 
                    WAREHOUSE.RAW_MULTISHIPPED.TRACKING_NO,
                    AVG(WAREHOUSE.RAW_MULTISHIPPED.FREIGHT) AS FREIGHT
                FROM WAREHOUSE.RAW_MULTISHIPPED
                WHERE warehouse.raw_multishipped.ORDER_NO=ORDERNUM
                GROUP BY WAREHOUSE.RAW_MULTISHIPPED.TRACKING_NO)
                COST);
END//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu problema es el tiempo de ejecución, todo apunta a que necesitas crearte un par de índices que le faciliten al servidor la tarea de localizar los registros necesarios para la consulta que ejecuta tu función:

```
ALTER TABLE raw_multishipped
  ADD INDEX(ORDER_NO);

ALTER TABLE raw_multishipped
  ADD INDEX(TRACKING_NO);
```